# Googlecast minicontroler onClose listener

Tags: android, android-widget, google-cast, android-tv

Is there a way to set action what happens inside app when I close the mini controller from the lock screen?

When I am casting, I lock my screen, I can control the cast with my `MiniController` in the lock screen. When I click the small X in the window, it closes the cast, but my `VideoCastControllerActivity` is still in the foreground when I unlock my device. At the same time I am disconnected from the cast.

I want to `finish()` the `VideoCastControllerActivity` when the user closes the `MiniController` with the X.

This X button is default widget button. I have not included it in the XML file.

I am using `CastCompanionLibrary 2.8.4`.

Comment: As  side note, what you see on the lock screen is actually the CCL's notification and not the MiniController. Regardless, if it doesn't happen automatically for you (i.e. clicking on X doesn't close the VideoCastControllerActivity), then I would consider that a bug. Please verify that this happens with CastVideos-android-v2 and if it does, please open a ticket on CCL's GitHub repo and I will take a look next week to address that.

Comment: I replicated this on the CastVideos-android-v2. It is happening there also.About to submit a ticket

Comment: Always include version numbers of libraries/SDKs used.